# librosa: interaction between n_fft and n_mels in melspectrogram

Tags: librosa

I just started toying around with `librosa`'s [mel spectrograms](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) and I'm a bit confused with the relationship between `n_fft` and `n_mels`. When I've worked with libraries `scipy` and `libfftw`, the number of bins was always dictated by the FFT length. Here, it seems like the two are independent? Or are they in fact connected? Thanks!